# non-const lvalue reference to type

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, visual-c++

Is there Visual Studio warning for the common GCC error,

`non-const lvalue reference to type`

I would like to make sure that such a coding paradigm is found, and an error thrown. According to a couple answers, already asked on SO, it sounds like it is just part of the MSVC++ compiler "extension". That is, there is no direct number.

My goal is to do something like,

`/weXYZW`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for [/Zc:referenceBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-referencebinding-enforce-reference-binding-rules)